# Rails redirect to a URL in View without JavaScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a file that has a URL, which I get and print using a Ruby on Rails View. What I want is to redirect to the URL I get from the file instead of printing it without using JavaScript and all things must be within the view. Here's the code I am using:

```
<% open('ngrok.log') do |f| %>
  <% f.lines.select { |line| line.include?("URL:") }.each do |line| %>
    Server available at: <%= line.match(/tcp:\/\/(.+:[0-9]+) /)[1] %>
    </br >
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Redirection should be done from the controller. I understand you think you have to do it this way, but you really shouldn't. And if you really really have to I guess javascript is the way to go.

Comment: Wait. "all things must be within the view"? You want to do a redirect from within the view? That seems like a uniquely bad idea. Views are templates for generating HTML. You already, IMO, have too much logic in your view. This all seems very unconventional.

Comment: You are just displaying the text from your log file here. As stated by @Joel_Blum you should redirect to whichever URL you need from controller. Not from view. If you should do it from view then you should use JavaScript.